# Django template not detecting certain keys while iterating over a dict

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am facing this weird issue:

These are three rows of a 'table' passed by view.py as printed out in Django template:

```
{'c2': {'tag_id': 'c2', 'display_id': 'C0002', 'name': 'Financial Statements', 'class': 'child-of-None', 'type': 'category', 'statement': 'N/A', 'jun_20': 0, 'jul_20': 0, 'aug_20': 0}, 'c1': {'tag_id': 'c1', 'display_id': 'C0001', 'name': 'Balance Sheet', 'class': 'child-of-2', 'type': 'category', 'statement': 'N/A', 'jun_20': 0.0, 'jul_20': 0.0, 'aug_20': 0.0}, 'c6': {'tag_id': 'c6', 'display_id': 'C0006', 'name': 'Non-Current Assets', 'class': 'child-of-1', 'type': 'category', 'statement': 'N/A', 'jun_20': 0.0, 'jul_20': 36750000000.0, 'aug_20': 0.0}}
```

This is a list of 'months' passed by views.py as printed out in Django template:

```
['jun_20', 'jul_20', 'aug_20']
```

And this is the code I am using to generate a table row:

```
        {% for content in table.values %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ content.display_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ content.name }}</td>
            {% for month in months %}
                <td>{{ content.month }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

And this is the output:

```
            <tr>
            <td>C0002</td>
            <td>Financial Statements</td>
            
                <td></td>
            
                <td></td>
            
                <td></td>
            
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>C0001</td>
            <td>Balance Sheet</td>
            
                <td></td>
            
                <td></td>
            
                <td></td>
            
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>C0006</td>
            <td>Non-Current Assets</td>
            
                <td></td>
            
                <td></td>
            
                <td></td>
            
        </tr>
```

Why are the month td tags blank?

If I change 'content.month' to 'content.jul_20, the tags do get the dictionary values for jul_20. I also tried converting the numbers stored as floats to strings.

Comment: Have you tried `<td>{{ content[month] }}</td>` at all?

Comment: tried. got the following error:
Could not parse the remainder: '[month]' from 'content[month]'